# Is there a hide property for pushbutton in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Is there a hide property for pushbutton in Qt Creator property pallet? I am trying to find one but I am not able to find. I need to make some buttons disable & some hide. Should I use property pallet for it OR do it in constructor? Later on user event, they will be enable & shown.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Some controls have "visibility" property on the palette, some don't. You always may do that programmatically (for example in the dialog's constructor):

```
MyButton->setVisible(false); //or true - later in the code
```

Comment: How to hide it from the Designer?

Comment: @YumYumYum **You can't,** because Qt (Creator|Designer) was intentionally crippled several years ago to prevent users from doing so. Because disabling critical and frankly trivial UI features that *had* been working stably for years is... good? I guess? See [this answer elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7843341/2809027) for further commentary.

Comment: Did you have a change to look at the answer's date? It's by the way was just 6 year ago :)

Comment: i still don't see it, and it is 2018

Answer (score 5):

In old versions of Qt Designer there was a property `visible` for it. But it seems that it was removed in new versions, so you can't use it directly.

But it is still possible to add this field in the .ui file. Just open any text editor, find the part related to the widget you need to hide, and insert this block in that place:

```
<property name="visible">
   <bool>false</bool>
</property>
```

Comment: **This is the only sane answer.** See [this answer elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7843341/2809027) for similar commentary. It numbs the imagination and the soul that in late 2017, Qt (Creator|Designer) *still* lacks support for hiding and showing widgets. `</sigh>`

Answer (score 1):

There is no property called hide, but there is one called "visible" that does what you want. See the QWidget (Since QPushButton is a QWisget) [docs](http://ttp://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#visible-prop) for more information.

Comment: Actually the QT Tutorial writes like 
     submitButton = new QPushButton(tr("&Submit"));
     submitButton->hide();
I also tried to find one like Visible but couldn't. Can you kindly tell where is it in property pallet ??

Comment: @enterprize It's not shown in the designer, but the property is there.

Comment: OK, thank you, probably I can use constructor then. But which property are you saying is not in Designer Hide OR Visible ? As I call hide from constructor & its there

Comment: @enterprize visible, hide() is just a function that just does setVisible(false), the same as visible = false.