# How do I set a default visibility value to a widget from QT-Designer?

Tags: c++, qt, svn

I need a way to set the visibility of a ***QGroupBox widget*** on QT to "false" ***by default***.

However, if I hardcoded it, the auto-generated header file of the "`.ui`" (that is "`ui_(x).h`") will be deleted whenever I do a project "Clean All", which means I have to re-hardcode it again .

This is a tedious job, specially in my case where I have to deal with SVN. The UI header-file (i.e.:"`ui_(x).h`") will not be committed when I do svn-commit (since it is auto-generated). Then when I do a svn-update on another machine the visibility will return to "***true***" again (since "***false***" is not the default visibility value) ..

How can I set a default visibility value on QT from QT-Designer (or even enforce the auto-generate engine to set specific value)?

Comment: Note, doing this from code right after doing the "setupui" should be easy way to achieve this outside Designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI_(x).h is generated from x.ui form file. If you set the groubbox to be hidden in x.ui file, I think this is what you want. Please refer to this link

[Initially hidden control in Qt Creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821481/initially-hidden-control-in-qt-creator)

Comment: U r very welcome, glad to be helpful.