# How to hide QLabel by default in QtDesigner

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer, qlabel

I've been working on project in Visual Studio and QtDesigner.
I want to set `QLabel(pixel, mm)` be invisible by default.
Someone have any idea ?

Comment: Not possible AFAIK. Just set it to invisible in the constructor.

Comment: yes. That's it. Done. Tks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initially hidden control in Qt Creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821481/initially-hidden-control-in-qt-creator)

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to set [QWidget visible-property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#visible-prop) in QtDesigner, see this question : [Initially hidden control in Qt Creator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7821481/6165833).

You need to do this through the code, in your parent constructor after initializing the UI objects:

```
ui->setupUi(this);
[...]
ui->myLabel->setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't control the `visible` property, But if you want to make `QLabel` looks invisible as default, just set the `width/height` property to `0`.